# How can get the closed border like left side in the right using highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

[image: enclosed border like in the left]

Guys, the issue I am facing is the left border in the left side has closed corner but in the right side X-lines and Y- lines are crossing. I want them like how it is in the left. I am using highcharts for the first time. Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you please share your highchart configurations?

Comment: xAxis: {
   offset: 0,
   min: 0,
   labels: false,
   gridLineColor: '#e6e6e6',
   gridLineWidth: 2,
   minorGridLineColor: '#f4f4f4',
   minorGridLineWidth: 1,
   minorTickLength: 0,
   minorTickInterval: 'auto'
  },
  yAxis: {
   offset: 0,
   labels: false,
   title: {
    text: ''
   },
   gridLineColor: '#e6e6e6',
   gridLineWidth: 2,
   minorGridLineColor: '#f4f4f4',
   minorGridLineWidth: 1,
   minorTickLength: 0,
   minorTickInterval: 'auto'
  }
@AdnanUmer

Answer (score 1):

The line on the left side of the plot in a default Highcharts configuration is the `yAxis` line.

To get an actual border around the plot area, use the `plotBorderWidth` and `plotBorderColor` properties.

Example:

```
chart: {
  plotBorderWidth: 1,
  plotBorderColor: 'rgba(204,0,0,1)'
}
```

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.plotBorderWidth
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.plotBorderColor

Fiddle Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/pozeqk81/

Output:

[image: screenshot]